# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, android

I pass string value to this method.but im getting Array index bound exception please help me.

```
public void separateCards(String cards)
{
    cardNames+=cards+"-";
    String[] parts = cardNames.split("-");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
    String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), part1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

My logcat

```
  03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
    03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at com.compareCr.ListvCompare.separateCards(ListvCompare.java:760)
    03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at com.compareCr.ListvCompare$2$1.onClick(ListvCompare.java:627)
    03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
    03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17356)
    03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    03-28 11:27:41.213: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Comment: what is your `String` that you are attempting to split over `-`

Comment: Is `cardNames = 004` and `cards = 034556`?

Comment: @Apoorv its cardName just like GoldeCard-platinumcard like that

Comment: Use this: `cardNames+="-"+cards;`. If u understand it, i'll add an answer.

Comment: it is unclear what does your string contain

Answer (score 3):

you append `"-"` at the end of the string and therefore when you split ,  you get only one value.

therefore this `String part2 = parts[1];` throw array index out of bound exception.

```
you need to put "-" in between string.
```

Comment: I grant you permission to use the code from my comment: `cardNames+="-"+cards;` :-)

Comment: thank you but i dont think to add that here. because i guess the question man has understand what was the problem.....:p

Answer (score 1):

You add the `-` in the wrong place. Giving you the value as(I assume the initial value of `cardNames` is `004`)

```
"004034556-"
```

You should do:

```
cardNames += "-" +cards;
```

Which will give you:

```
"004-34556"
```

But seriously what is the purpose of combining the `String` and `split` it again at the same way?

Wouldn't it be easy if you just do like this?

```
String part1 = cardNames; 
String part2 = cards;
```

**Note:** You should always check that the `index` element that you want to access must **less** that `parts.length`

Comment: Care to explain _how_ this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is only single "**-**" in your **cardNames** value, that's why you getting error..

So better to use For loop for getting all data from Array

```
    String[] parts = cardNames.split("-");
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        String partsData = parts[i]; 
    }
```

**Updated:**

```
cardNames=cardNames+"-"+cards;

String parts1;
String parts2;
String[] parts = cardNames.split("-");
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if(i==0)
        parts1= parts[i];
    else if(i==1)
        parts2= parts[i];
}
```

Comment: i want to divide becouse i want to save in two strings.how do i do that please help me

Comment: First you merge two string after then you divide it, why this so ??

Answer (score 0):

When something with no "-" passed into your method,
like "foo"
it become "foo-"
when u call "foo-".split()
it returns ["foo"]
therefore if u try to access index 1, it is out of bound.

Answer (score -1):

Have you print "cards"?

I think cardNames is "somethig-";
then parts = {'something'}

so, parts[1] is out of index.